# How to forward emails in MailWise

Tags: email, exchange

I use MailWise to check my Exchange emails.

Now I need to forward an email, but I can't find the function for it.

Can you tell me where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the email you would like to forward.

Click on the "more" 3 dots. it is there under Reply all.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works, **if the mail has content**. My email is a forwarded one and when I press the 3 dots, it just collapses or expands. Strange behavior.